# Adding a 'provided' configuration to a kotlin/java library using gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have a java library to which I've added a 'provided' configuration using gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply from: file('../gradle/gradle-mvn-push.gradle')

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group = GROUP
version = VERSION_NAME

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}
javadoc.classpath += configurations.provided

idea {
    module {
        scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided]
    }
}

checkstyle {
    configFile = new File(rootDir, 'checkstyle.xml')
    toolVersion = '6.7'
}

dependencies {
    provided 'com.google.android:android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.workday:metajava:1.0'
}
```

Everything works as expected with this setup.

Now I want to start using kotlin in my library, so I modified the build script to look like this (sans pluses)

```
+buildscript {
+    repositories {
+        mavenCentral()
+    }
+    dependencies {
+        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.12.613"
+    }
+}
 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'idea'
+apply plugin: 'kotlin'
 apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
 apply from: file('../gradle/gradle-mvn-push.gradle')

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group = GROUP
version = VERSION_NAME

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}
javadoc.classpath += configurations.provided

idea {
    module {
        scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided]
    }
}

checkstyle {
    configFile = new File(rootDir, 'checkstyle.xml')
    toolVersion = '6.7'
}

dependencies {
    provided 'com.google.android:android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.workday:metajava:1.0'
+   compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:0.12.613"
}
```

Without even adding any kotlin files (and even if I do), the library no longer compiles saying that it can't find the classes in the provided library (android in my case).

What do I need to change to get it so that the provided dependencies are recognized again?

Comment: Interesting approach - since you "provide" the Android Framework API, I assume you want to create an Android library? Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you use a plain Android library project? Kotlin integration works fine for that kind of project. But maybe I miss a requirement you need?

Comment: @SteffenFunke, the library is a code generation library using annotation processors, so it can't be an actual android library. The full thing is on [github](https://github.com/Workday/postman) if you would like to see it.

Comment: Instead of custom code, use one of the prebuilt nicely available plugins for Gradle that do this.  I added information below.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I do it in a Gradle plugin:

```
private void addProvidedConfiguration() {
  final Configuration provided =
      addConfiguration(project.configurations, "provided")
  final Javadoc javadoc =
      project.tasks.getByName(JavaPlugin.JAVADOC_TASK_NAME) as Javadoc
  javadoc.classpath = javadoc.classpath.plus(provided)
}

private static Configuration addConfiguration(
    final ConfigurationContainer configurations, final String name) {
  final Configuration compile =
      configurations.getByName(JavaPlugin.COMPILE_CONFIGURATION_NAME)
  final Configuration configuration = configurations.create(name)

  compile.extendsFrom(configuration)
  configuration.visible = false
  configuration.transitive = false

  configuration.allDependencies.all { final dependency ->
    configurations.default.exclude(group: dependency.group, module: dependency.name)
  }

  return configuration
}
```

You can check the source code on [github](https://github.com/MichaelRocks/lightsaber/blob/develop/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/io/michaelrocks/bintray/BintrayPlugin.groovy).

Answer (score 0):

This [`gradle-propdeps` plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/gradle-plugins/tree/master/propdeps-plugin) adds `provided` and `optional` to Gradle, and also handles its integration into IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse.  It is from the Spring team and it has a lot of usage.

You should apply the `kotlin` plugin after `propdeps`.

I have not tested this with Android libraries, but it is a much safer bet than trying to roll your own.  There are little special cases to handle.

An alternative plugin, also used heavily is [the one from Netflix team](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-extra-configurations-plugin) who has many plugins available for different useful additions to Gradle.  This plugin adds the same `provided` and `optional`.

This is a good reminder that the old issue [Provide a 'provided' configuration](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-784) for Gradle is still outstanding for 6 years, and feel free to provide your opinion there as to the lack of this feature.